# Spring 4 HttpSession different for each controller method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Say I have two controllers:

```
@Controller
public class SetUserController
{

  @PostMapping("/setUser")
  public setUser( @RequestBody User user, HttpSession session)
  {
    session.setAttribute("user", user);
    return "index";
  }
}
```

...

```
@Controller
public class GetUserController
{

  @GetMapping("/getUser")
  public getUser( HttpSession session)
  {
    User user = (User)session.getAttribute("user");
    return "index";

   }
}
```

In the GetUserController#getUser method the session is a completely new session (isNew=true and it has a different ID), so obviously the session.getAttribute() will always return null. Does the dispatcher servlet create a new HttpSession object for each request? If so... WHY?!

I'm running this on Tomcat 8.

Comment: First, the dispatcher servlet does not create a new session for every request. You are hitting the setUser URL first, with a valid User object passed in? And you are seeing the JSESSIONID cookie set in that first response, and returned in the second request to getUser?

Comment: There is an index page that gets hit first. There is a JSESSIONID cookie created when the index page is hit. If I create a breakpoint in the setUser and getUser methods the ID for the HttpSession object is different for both and the isNew is set to true, so something is creating a new HttpSession object for each request. The above code is just an example, yes assume that the User object is valid.

Comment: The sessions won't be new just from the above code. Either the JSESSIONID cookie isn't being returned (like if it's Secure-only and not on https), or some other code is invalidating the session.

Answer (score 0):

Check your path JSESSIONID cookie or how you do redirect.

Or try to config your cookies like this.

If you have web.xml

```
<session-config>
  <cookie-config>
     <name>JSESSIONID</name>
     <path>/</path>
     <http-only>true</http-only>
     <secure>true</secure>
  </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

If you use spring boot:

```
    server.servlet.session.cookie.path= /
    server.servlet.session.cookie.name= JSESSIONID
    server.servlet.session.cookie.http-only= true
    server.servlet.session.cookie.secure= true
```

And now the session variables are working across sessions. Of course, now the session variables don't work when running using localhost. Instead you can set the sessionCookiePath on the context.xml root context node:

I'm using ubuntu server and tomcat8. For tomcat8, the context.xml can be found at /etc/tomcat8/context.xml.

...

Now, you should be able to run locally (if you didn't change that cookiepath on your local machine) as well as on the server without having to configure the JSESSIONID cookie in your apps web.xml.